# Validate varchar datatype value to format HH:MM

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

I have a column `test_mac` with data type `varchar`.

For eg following values will be there in that column :

```
create table test_mac
(
     time_in varchar(200)
)

insert into test_mac values ('23:15')
insert into test_mac values ('23:1')
insert into test_mac values ('23:12')
insert into test_mac values ('sdfdsfs')
insert into test_mac values ('23/15')
insert into test_mac values ('2315')
insert into test_mac values ('2:15')
insert into test_mac values ('23:')
```

I am doing this currently :

```
select * 
from test_mac   
where time_in LIKE '%[0-2][0-9]:[0-5][0-59]'
   and ISDATE(time_in) = 1
```

Expected result I require is:

```
23:15 
23:1 
23:12 
 2:15
```

should be valid times. If there are value as 23:1 I have to update them to 23:10 or for 2:15 to 02:15,

**NOTE**:

Above is just an creation of test data.Have got to apply some where to just input valid time

Comment: please tag the version of sql you are using

Comment: Read Aaron Bertrand's [Bad habits to kick : choosing the wrong data type](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/12/bad-habits-to-kick-choosing-the-wrong-data-type)

Comment: @ZoharPeled you can't help out if already the architect has designed to do so and you gotcha chance to work on it as an issue

Comment: @Malcom actually if it is an issue in the system it might be an excellent opportunity to fix the problem instead of hacking a solution. By far the best way to solve this is by using the correct datatype. Using varchar for time is just as absurd as storing an int in xml.

Comment: Do you want to update the records or just select them?

Comment: @Malcolm: using `varchar` instead of  `time`  is a **really** bad choice. Feel free to send links to these comments to your so-called architect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If a beautiful solution isn't what you're looking for, here's a slightly long-winded hacky solution I wrote quickly to do the job, it's been lightly tested and works on your sample data:

```
CREATE TABLE #test_mac
    (
      time_in VARCHAR(200) ,
      formatted VARCHAR(10)
    );

INSERT  INTO #test_mac
VALUES  ( '23:15', NULL ),
        ( '23:1', NULL ),
        ( '23:12', NULL ),
        ( 'sdfdsfs', NULL ),
        ( '23/15', NULL ),
        ( '2315', NULL ),
        ( '2:15', NULL ),
        ( '23:', NULL );


UPDATE  #test_mac
SET     formatted = CASE WHEN LEN(SUBSTRING(time_in, 0,
                                            CHARINDEX(':', time_in))) = 2
                         THEN SUBSTRING(time_in, 0, CHARINDEX(':', time_in))
                         ELSE '0' + SUBSTRING(time_in, 0,
                                              CHARINDEX(':', time_in))
                    END + ':'
        + CASE WHEN LEN(SUBSTRING(time_in, CHARINDEX(':', time_in) + 1, 2)) = 2
               THEN SUBSTRING(time_in, CHARINDEX(':', time_in) + 1, 2)
               ELSE SUBSTRING(time_in, CHARINDEX(':', time_in) + 1, 1) + '0'
          END
WHERE   time_in LIKE '%[0-9]:[0-5]%' -- looks for a single digit before & after
        AND LEN(time_in) <= 5; -- length must be 5 characters or less

SELECT  *
FROM    #test_mac
WHERE   formatted IS NOT NULL;

DROP TABLE #test_mac;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`try_convert`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh230993.aspx) to do this. Invalid values will show up as `null`.

```
select time_in,try_convert(time,time_in) 
from test_mac
```

Edit: To treat values which don't have a `:` character in them, you can use a `case` expression.

```
select time_in,
case when charindex(':',time_in) = 0 then null else try_convert(time,time_in) end
from test_max
```

Also the assumption that `23:1` should be converted to `23:10` is false. Imagine you have a value like `23:6`, it should be converted to `23:06` instead of `23:60`.

Comment: it looks good but for data 23:1 it displays as 23:01, which should be 23:10 and also it includes 2315 which should be invalid due to missing :